# Show "birthday" days in format 'dd.mm' from format 'dd.mm.yy' but only if that "birthday" has more than 10 employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to show "birthday" days in format 'dd.mm' from format 'dd.mm.yy' but only if that "birthday" has more than 10 employees from table named "employeeFirm".

when I go : `select birthday from employeeFirm;` 
I get:

```
01.11.73
08.09.77
01.11.65
01.11.74
(null)
(null)
01.11.85
(null)
01.11.88
01.11.65
01.11.56
01.11.77
01.11.77
(null)
01.11.77
01.11.77 
....
```

I want to get a record in format 'dd.mm', in this case ofcorse " 01.11" because we have more than 10 employees with the same day birthday.

Comment: So what have you been taught about recently... I'm guessing aggregate functions like count, grouping, and the having clause? And formatting dates as strings?

Comment: yes, just count grouping having, and formatting dates because I have to get just DDMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ddmm, count
FROM (
    SELECT distinct Substr(Birthday,1,5) as ddmm
        , Count(Birthday) OVER(PARTITION BY  Substr(Birthday,1,5)) AS count
    from employeeFirm
) A
where count> 10
```

Comment: How can I in this query also ask how much birthdays there are? eg: 01.08    5, 05.03.    16

Comment: what do you mean? you want to see all existing birthdays?

Comment: no.. I just want to count, for example if there is a birthday on a date 01.08 and 16 employees has birthdays on that date, I want to get this number.. (16). And if another birthday is on 08.08 and has 18 employees, i want to get this number (18)

Comment: not for all birthdays, but just for the birthdays that are >10 ..I mean, for example if the date 09.09 is > 10 employees, than i want to count that number to see how much employees does have birthday on that date...

Answer (score 2):

You can use TO_CHAR like this:

```
SELECT case when t.formated is not null
            then t.formated
            else to_char(s.birthday,'DD.MM.YYYY')
       end as new_birthDay
FROM employeeFirm s
LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT TO_CHAR(birthday,'DD.MM') as formated
                FROM employeeFirm
                GROUP BY TO_CHAR(birthday,'DD.MM') 
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 10) t
ON(to_char(s.birthday,'DD.MM') = t.formated)
```

If you only want the birthdays that has more then 10 employees on that day then :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(birthday,'DD.MM') as formated
FROM employeeFirm
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(birthday,'DD.MM') 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

Comment: If I understood task correctly your subquery is expected result =)

Comment: the result is " not a group by expression"

Comment: @SkyWalker Maybe :P not sure what he meant.

Comment: Great, I'll appreciate an approval then @GoranBartBartolić

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS 
(SELECT dob,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dob ORDER BY dob) counting FROM employeeFirm)
SELECT dob,
CASE WHEN counting >10 
THEN to_char(dob,'DD-MM') ELSE to_char(dob,'DD-MM-YYYY') 
end  
FROM t;
```